# How to make a simple VR video player by Google CardBoard Android SDK and Rajawali

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, rajawali

I am a new man in these area. I am trying to change a [program](https://github.com/ejeinc/RajawaliCardboardExample) in github to play video for cardboard now.

I modified the MyRenderer by using StreamingTexture.

```
public class MyRenderer extends RajawaliCardboardRenderer {

public MyRenderer(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private StreamingTexture streamingTexture;

@Override
protected void initScene() {
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.getContext(), R.raw.test);

    streamingTexture = new StreamingTexture("video", mMediaPlayer);
    Sphere sphere = createPhotoSphereWithTexture(streamingTexture);

    getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere);

    getCurrentCamera().setPosition(Vector3.ZERO);
    getCurrentCamera().setFieldOfView(75);
}

private static Sphere createPhotoSphereWithTexture(ATexture texture) {

    Material material = new Material();
    material.setColor(0);

    try {
        material.addTexture(texture);
    } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50, 64, 32);
    sphere.setScaleX(-1);
    sphere.setMaterial(material);

    return sphere;
}
}
```

I saved my short video as test.mp4 in the raw folder, however , after I start my app the two sides are blank, and the video's sound is actually playing.

I need some help. Thank you very much!

Comment: you can try my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391282/how-to-use-rajawalivr-or-rajawali-to-play-a-360-video

Answer (score 5):

I got 360 video with head tracking in a carboard working like this.

Extend your class using [RajawaliVRRenderer](https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliVR)

```
public class YoureVideoClass extends RajawaliVRRenderer {
```

next use the following initScene():

```
    @Override
public void initScene() {

    // setup sphere
    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(1, 100, 100);
    sphere.setPosition(0, 0, 0);
    // invert the sphere normals
    // factor "1" is two small and result in rendering glitches
    sphere.setScaleX(100);
    sphere.setScaleY(100);
    sphere.setScaleZ(-100);

    //initiate MediaPlayer
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    try {
        Uri videoUrl = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.test);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(),Uri.parse(videoUrl));
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();    //prepare the player (asynchronous)
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start(); //start the player only when it is prepared
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // create texture from media player video
    videoTexture = new StreamingTexture("video", mediaPlayer);

    // set material with video texture
    Material material = new Material();
    material.setColorInfluence(0f);
    try {
        material.addTexture(videoTexture);
    } catch (ATexture.TextureException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    sphere.setMaterial(material);

    // add sphere to scene
    getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere);

    super.initScene();
}
```

After initiating the scene you want to update the videoTexture on every render, so add:

```
@Override
public void onRender(long elapsedRealTime, double deltaTime) {
    super.onRender(elapsedRealTime, deltaTime);

    if (videoTexture != null) {
        // update texture from video content
        videoTexture.update();
    }
}
```

And last but not least you want to update the camera for movement tracking for the cardboard like this:

```
@Override
public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {
    // Rajawali camera
    org.rajawali3d.cameras.Camera currentCamera = getCurrentCamera();

    // cardboard field of view
    FieldOfView fov = eye.getFov();

    // update Rajawali camera from cardboard sdk
    currentCamera.updatePerspective(fov.getLeft(), fov.getRight(), fov.getBottom(), fov.getTop());
    eyeMatrix.setAll(eye.getEyeView());
    // orientation
    eyeOrientation.fromMatrix(eyeMatrix);
    currentCamera.setOrientation(eyeOrientation);
    // position
    eyePosition = eyeMatrix.getTranslation().inverse();
    currentCamera.setPosition(eyePosition);

    // render with Rajawali
    super.onRenderFrame(null);
}
```

Also, to pass some other listeners forward to the carboard sdk you will need these functions:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) {
    // tell Rajawali that cardboard sdk detected a size change
    super.onRenderSurfaceSizeChanged(null, width, height);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    // pass opengl config to Rajawali
    super.onRenderSurfaceCreated(eglConfig, null, -1, -1);
}

@Override
public void onRenderSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    super.onRenderSurfaceDestroyed(surface);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much！You have shown such a detailed solution. I have implement it with [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391282/how-to-use-rajawalivr-or-rajawali-to-play-a-360-video) before. Your answer should also be very helpful to me.