# Android VR player

Tags: android, video, google-cardboard, rajawalivr

I am little new to **Virtual Reality** concept in android and also developed one sample demo with `Rajawali VR` library to show video side by side and watch it with `CardBoard`.

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391771/how-to-make-a-simple-vr-video-player-by-google-cardboard-android-sdk-and-rajawal) link which also help for Head Tracking, but I want to show normal videos (I mean not 360 video), like same way in Side by Side [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funghisoft.sbsvideoplayer&hl=en).

Actually I want to know which View should I use instead of Sphere, because to see normal video with `CardBoard` we need some flat surface to play video in it side by side.

So please kindly help in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ScreenQuad material primitives of rajawali and then set the scale accordingly.It will be worked.

Comment: Thanks Bhavin. I tried and for I can say this is good work around.